# Why didn't flooded extension cord plug trip breaker?

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, safety, flooding

I had an issue recently where my cat turned on a [laundry tub faucet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5zL0.png), flooding the basement with municipal water (due to the [floor drain being clogged](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8RjS.png); 1930 house in the Toronto area).

There was a live extension cord plug (connected to the clothes washer; off) fully submerged in 4 inches of water. I was surprised that the submerged extension cord plug didn't trip the breaker. It actually would have been preferable if the breaker had tripped, because otherwise, I had to wade through the water (possibly electrified) in rubber boots to get to the breaker to cut the power, which seemed risky, and then wade over to turn the tap off.

Why didn't the live extension cord plug short to ground, tripping the breaker? For example, I would have thought it would have shorted, possibly shorting to ground through the [cast iron drain pipe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aks0o.jpg) in the floor.

(I don't have any experience with electrical stuff; feel free to correct my terminology.)

Comment: The circuit breaker is designed to trip with current above a certain amount. Fresh water, with no salt in it, doesn't conduct electricity very well. Also, the "ground" that would complete a short circuit is the "equipment ground", the third wire in a 3-prong outlet, not the actual dirt/earth. I suspect your drain pipes are not connected by wire(s) to your electrical system's ground (although your cold/hot water pipes if metal likely are).

Comment: When you say "fully submerged" do you actually mean at the end? The cable itself is waterproof but the connectors aren't. Do you have an earth leakage breaker (GFCI)? That will trip on a small fault to ground and while common in wet locations they're by no means universal. A normal circuit breaker will trip on overcurrent, with the speed depending on the amount of overcurrent

Comment: @ChrisH *"When you say "fully submerged" do you actually mean at the end?"* Yes, at the end, at the connector. No, I don't have a GFCI.

Comment: I once waded into a flooded Bank to turn off some servers on a table, perhaps ankle deep.  I hit the wall switch and they didn't go off but there started a click and beeping.  Turns out there was a UPS on the floor, half submerged.   That was a time-slowing moment, realising that there was probably mere centimetres between the dirty water and the energised electrics inside.  After considering my options, I slowly moved to the UPS and held down its power button with a plastic pen from my pocket.  It went off along with the computers.  Phew!

Comment: Prob because it was actually submerged. Get 'em wet and they'll pop. Give them a load to start boiling water and it'll be fine. But put yourself in the ~2' circle between where it's otherwise leaking to ground... and *you* won't be. You're in parallel at an extremely high resistance until you get too close. And then you start being in series and become a conductor.

Comment: @User1974 You should update the question to note that the plug on the extension cord was submurged so that people coming to this question understand that without having to dig through the comments. (My first thought was that very same question.)

Comment: @armand I'm surprised that your comment has gathered so many up votes. The OP was spot-on to be concerned that a basement floor drain in a 1930 house in Toronto would constitute a very effective electrical ground. I think you have misunderstood why electrical ground is called "ground." It's because it comes from the ground! You were correct about all other points, though.

Comment: @AldusBumblebore I was wondering about that, too. If the dirt was not the actual ground (and, hence, neutral) there would be no danger in touching live wires. I think I read somewhere that houses in some Scandinavian country have in-house 1:1 transformers which serve no other purpose than to galvanically  decouple the neutral from Earth; it is impossible to electrocute oneself by touching a live wire. But that is not the case in the majority of installations in other parts of the world.

Comment: @Armand You are incorrect. There is a relationship between the literal ground/earth and the equipment ground. Buildings connect that ground (to which the third prongs go) into the earth with a metal stake.  A flooded extension cord connected to ground via mildly conducting water will likely trip a GFCI.

Comment: Basements require GFCI protection on receptacles........ and this is why.

Comment: @AldusBumblebore  To clarify, I was suggesting why the breaker did not make an (overcurrent) trip.  The earth should indeed be in contact with the equipment ground via the grounding electrode system, but it is not a good conductor and so unlikely to conduct the tens of amps of current needed to trip the breaker. Of course, injuring a person requires much less current, which is why AFCI breakers/outlets were developed, which trigger at tiny amounts of unintended current. As others have noted, the OP should prioritize installing AFCI.

Comment: @armand Ahh, yes I do see that, now that I reread your original comment. I had interpreted that portion as a response to the OP's comment about the safety concerns regarding wading through it. I see now that I misinterpreted that.

Answer (score 19):

Good thinking on the rubber boots, but next time call the power company, or find some other way to turn off the power.

Without a GFCI municipal water will not conduct enough current to trip a breaker, but will still conduct enough to paralyze you. (and then you drown)
So you only get one chance, if you slip on something and fall in the water, you're toast (or perhaps soup)

As mentioned in comments installing GFCI outlets (or GFCI breakers if the outlets are located below the flood line) is probably a good idea.  NEC requires GFCI outlets in new-build laundry areas.

Comment: This would be a good time to install GFCI receptacles in the basement, which will trip if this happens again.

Comment: @Mark That may not help much if the receptacle itself gets submerged, as there'll still be contact with the live wires leading up to it.

Comment: Better still - don't connect your washer to the mains via an extension lead. Arrange a GFCI protected socket to be near the appliance.

Comment: Surely the electricity is going to conduct from the live pin to the ground pin in the extension cord (path of least resistance). Why would it conduct from the live pin, through the water, through the person, to some other route to ground?

Comment: "shortest/easiest  path only" is a myth. it goes by every path,  this is why the lights don't go out when you turn on the toaster.

Comment: It does go to every path, proportional to resistance - to some extent. Lights and toaster show a similar path, but the short trip through two leads vs the long trip through the person do not.

Comment: To be clear, I am not at all advocating the idea of going through potentially electrified water - it is just that touching it is most probably not going to do anything to you, but there are a thousand other things that can go wrong.

Comment: The field will be stronger closer to the fault. and it will mostly be a dipole field (so 1/r^4) so yeah you will probably survive.

Comment: @Mark: How about putting the master cutoff switch at a higher level of the house?

Answer (score 12):

It probably did short to ground (and to neutral). But that doesn’t actually trip the breaker reliably unless it’s a GFCI breaker *or* the short draws enough current to hit the trip point on the breaker, which it almost certainly did not.

Given that you mention the device plugged in is a washing machine, it’s probably a NEMA 5-15 or NEMA 5-20 plug. That means hot has 12.7mm of water to cover to short to neutral, and equivalent to ground. Good tap water typically has a resistance on the order of about 2 kΩ per meter. That gives us roughly 25.4 Ω of resistance, which at 120 V translates to just short of 5 A across the ‘short’ between hot and neutral, and the same to ground. Leakage beyond that is probably negligible in this case, so we’re looking at around 10-12 A. But your washing machine *should* be on a dedicated 15 A or 20 A circuit, and that’s not enough to trip the breaker for such a circuit.

To actually trip a 15 A breaker you need a short with a resistance of 8 Ω or less, and a 20 A breaker needs a short with a resistance of 6 Ω or less. That’s actually possible with tap water in some places, but it’s rather uncommon in more populous parts of North America or Europe.

Now, this does not mean that wading through the water was safe, even with well insulated boots. Water’s conductivity is very closely related to what’s dissolved in it and how much, your skin has plenty of stuff on the surface to dissolve into the water to raise that conductivity. Factoring that in, if you got close enough to the end of the extension cord (or to an outlet in the wall) and fell into the water, you very likely would have been paralyzed, and probably drowned as a result.

In the future, it’s much safer to call the power company for a temporary shutoff. Also, you probably should take the time to install GFCI breakers for all the basement circuits (not just this one) as they would have tripped in the described situation, and possibly look into better drainage to help avoid such scenarios.

Comment: Which all points to the benefit (though up-front cost can be significant) of an outside whole-service disconnect switch.

Comment: So, another method would have been to throw some salt in the water...

Comment: @Toffomat In theory yes, but with the volume of water likely involved, it would have had to be a _lot_ of salt.

Comment: "That’s actually possible with tap water in some places, but it’s rather uncommon in more populous parts of North America". A very good point, especially regarding "more populous". I rather suspect that my well water, pre-treatment, is in fact able to conduct that much current: so if I had a leak at between the entry to the house and the treatment system, I'd be at risk. Fortunately, 21st century electrical codes and whole house GFCI.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn Of course, this wasn't serious, but now you somewhat nerd-sniped me. The resistivity data for salt water seems disorganised and inconcistetnt, but a concentration of 1% would certainly suffice for good enough conductivity. For a plausible basement of 10*10 m^2, flooded to 1 m (so you can wade through with high boots), this requires a ton of rock salt, which costs only about 60$, so likely cheaper than an electrician (but shipping not included)...

Answer (score 0):

I worked with an electrician who serviced a lot of commercial installations, so I got to learn a little about the difference between things like GFCI / C/AFCI but this guy explains it very well:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E3rTqsL-CRU

Moreover I've lived in a house where a breaker remained engaged during a dead short and the wiring  began to burn up inside of a wall and it almost burned down the house. The cost of good breakers is rather prohibitive:

https://www.bogleheads.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=371755

For the most part what people are suggesting elsewhere in this thread about GFCI outlets, they're absolutely correct, but your breakers are also designed to operate a particular way depending on what you have and there are different kinds. Based on what you've described the water despite completing a circuit between hot and neutral didn't sink enough current to trip the breaker; my understanding is that a C/AFCI would absolutely fault if you completed a direct circuit between hot and ground; a qualified electrician can (and should be) the one to confirm that for you.

I would get the models of all of my breakers and find out what kind they are, and if you kinda understand the theory so far about different kinds of breakers and their operational characteristics maybe even cross check what is code. Moreover what is code is not necessarily the same thing as what is safe; code can be a minimum.

Ultimately I would have an electrician make an assessment and just know that if they're reasonable it's unlikely that they're going to recommend anything that they couldn't personally justify for themselves--not out of necessity; most of their clients probably can't understand or don't care that much. Absolutely ask questions and if possible have your own opinions because ultimately it's your house.

But again I can't emphasize this enough; find a qualified professional for an assessment.

Comment: This is also a very informative video on the subject (series vs parallel arc fault protection): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jMjBGzyoWUY

Also, testing your AFCI protected circuits: https://www.youtube.com/shorts/wvVbf4TR8Ok

Comment: As informative as it may be, it does not answer the question.  You need to answer teh question instead of asking readers to watch two videos.